# Avoid loop causing overload

Tags: android, loops, try-catch

I am developing an android game where I have a loop (not a game loop). This loop reacts if one of my booleans is changed. The problem is that when the boolean is changed, it calls the void inside the loop untill the app crashes of an overload. The void I am calling is suronded with a try-catch and it has to be, unless I have to remake the rest of my game. The code for the loop is like so:

```
private void listenerVoid(){
  int timeBetweenChecks = 100;
  final Handler h = new Handler();
  h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
      //Do something if myBool returns true, otherwise loop again
      if (myBool==false){
        listenerVoid();

      } else {  
        //Check if the listener has reacted to a change before 
        if(firstStart!=false){
          firstStart = false;
          theTryCatchVoid();  
          Log.i("MyClass","Boolean is changed");
        }
        else{
          //Already started
          Log.i("MyClass","Already started");
        }
      }
    }
  }, timeBetweenChecks);
};
```

And my try-catch void is similar to this:

```
private void tryCatchVoid(){
  try{
    //Try to do something that soemtimes causes a crash
  }
  catch(Exception e){
    //Do nothing
  }
}
```

I can not increase the `timeBetweenChecks` time, because it will then cause a long waiting time in my game. How can I make the `tryCatchVoid` only be called once?

Comment: I'm guessing you can't do this, but wouldn't it be easier to call the `tryCatchVoid()` method from the part of code which sets that `boolean` value?

Comment: @Luksprog I do not think that would work in my case. I have already tried using a Local Broadcast Manager with no luck, and makeing the void I am going to call static would be relly hard.